# In WPF, why is my "Content Changed" custom routed event works only when the content changes outside of the frame?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

I have this custom `Frame` class:

```
public class cstmFrame : Frame
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ContentChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(cstmFrame));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, this));
    }
}
```

Whenever the content changes, I trigger an animation:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:cstmFrame.ContentChanged">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource stbFadePageIn}" />
</EventTrigger>
```

Now, when I am changing the content from outside the frame (from the `MainWindow`), the animation works perfectly:

```
FrameName.Navigate(new Page1());
```

*(**Note:** Before, I used `FrameName.content = new Page1();`, but both works for me)*

The problem comes when I am trying to switch pages from within one of the pages. So, for example, if I am inside `Page1`, and I want to navigate to `Page2` I use the following code, and it works, except the animation does not start:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
```

**I have two questions:**

1. What is the problem with **my** code?
2. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Bit lazy to create a sample to reproduce the issue. . If possible, Can you make it. . ?

Comment: @Gopichandar - I do not know how... Could you still help me, please?